# Magento 2 - 404 on category page if said category has no products

Tags: magento2, 404-page, sub-categories

I've got a problem with category pages: whenever a subcategory has any number of products inside, then the category page works. But, if the subcategory is empty, it just returns 404, not "no items in this category" or something like that, just 404, even if i select "show blocks and products", it doesn't find the page. Not even if I try to reach it via /catalog/category/view/id/xxx...
I'm absolutely clueless as to why this happens. Has anyone got any idea? I've already looked for solutions on google and stack-overflow, but I didn't find anything related to my specific problem. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I've also tried to indexer:reindex and setup:static-content:deploy, but to no effect...

Comment: Did you check URL exists in url_rewrite?

Comment: Yes, it does, and it looks something like request: /category/category/category.html; target: /catalog/category/view/id/xxx

Comment: Please try manual URL like, http://localhost/magento227/<your category URL Key which is in "Search Engine Optimization">.html

Comment: you mean like mydomain.com/category/subcategory.html (with category and subcategory being URL keys from SEO)? I've tried that

Comment: Then need to check more, Please check log

Comment: My last exception is [2019-05-18 03:05:36] main.CRITICAL: Warning: file_put_contents(): Only 4 of 51 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space in /home/kahunashop/test.kahunashop.it/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 663 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning: file_put_contents(): Only 4 of 51 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space in /home/kahunashop/test.kahunashop.it But the server guy solved it and it's pretty old